# python numpy array intepretation

Tags: python, numpy

I have problem in interpret the numpy array in python, for example,

```
data[:,i:i+3, j:j+3]
```

if i =2, j =1, then it would be `data[ :, 2: 5,1:4]`
suppose the whole data array look like this:

```
data =([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]])
```

then what does the array  `data[ :, 2: 5,1:4]` look like? I really don't understand what does the colon `:` mean, and what does the comma `,` here mean?

Comment: You _wouldn't_ slice that `data` with the expression above.  Notice that there are 3 slices being passed -- each slice corresponds to a particular dimension in the array.  Since you have 2 dimensional data, you wouldn't pass 3 slices, only 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python advanced slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38988560/python-advanced-slicing)

Comment: Or even basic indexing; the `:` is used in list indexing; the `,` is fundamental to indexing multidimensions in `numpy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a use of the index pattern:

Make a 3d array, with shape large enough to accommodate this index;

```
In [568]: data=np.arange(2*6*5).reshape(2,6,5)
In [569]: data[:, 2:5, 1:4]
Out[569]: 
array([[[11, 12, 13],
        [16, 17, 18],
        [21, 22, 23]],

       [[41, 42, 43],
        [46, 47, 48],
        [51, 52, 53]]])
```

The result is a (2,3,3) array.  If we think of the 3d array as having planes, rows and columns, this returns all planes, 3 rows, and 3 columns.  It may help to print out `data` and identify the elements that have been selected.  I made them unique to make this easier.

This is an example of basic indexing (all indexing terms are slices):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing